# How to control which connection is selected from the database.yml in a symfony1.4 task

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

**(See my edit below for a better question)** How do I control which connection is selected (from the right environment section in the database.yml) in a symfony1.4 task using just a generic `Doctrine_Query::create()` to create the query?

I'm using a database.yml that looks something like this:

```
prod:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql://some:pass@domain:port/database

  log:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql://some:pass@domain:port/database
  auth:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql://some:pass@domain:port/database

dev:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql://some:otherpass@domain:port/database

  log:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql://some:otherpass@domain:port/database

  auth:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql://some:otherpass@domain:port/database
```

And I want to be able to control which one of those database definitions is used when calling something like:

```php
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('Products p')
        ->where('p.id = ?', $productID)
        ->limit(1);

$OfpFlPr = $query->execute()->getFirst();
```

At the moment I'm not able to set the connection like so `$query = Doctrine_Query::create($conn);`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

I have lots of code deeper in the software where `Doctrine_Query::create()` is used (without the connection argument). It seems to select the right environment and connection through web requests. But I can't figure out how it does this, so I can make my **CLI commands** work the same way (they don't select the right connection and environment at the moment). That's why I need to know how to control which connection is 'automaticly' used (selected by default).

**Question:**

So I guess in conclusion my question would be:

*How can I control which connection is selected by default in lower level code which uses `Doctrine_Query::create()` while the code is being executed as a symfony CLI command?*

Comment: Do you mean that product table is duplicated in each database, or do you have tables spread across multiple databases?

Comment: Both actually. Tables are spread across multiple databases and they are duplicated  across multiple environments (in this case `prod` and `dev`). Lets say (for the sake of the example) that the product table is available over the `prod.auth` as well as the `dev.auth` connection.

Comment: @Marek: I think I might have misunderstood you. For clarity, neither the product table nor any other tables that is referenced in the `schema.yml` is spread over multiple databases in my set up. It can however exist in both environments. And for each environment it should exist under the same connection name.

Comment: Specifying connection in schema.yml would not work? Eg `connection: doctrine` on Product, `connection: log` on Log model.

Comment: Not sure, I'll give it a try.

Comment: The connection was already correctly specified in the `schema.yml` for the `Product` class (and the rest of the classes as well). I guess it is more of an issue with selecting the (correctly specified) connection from the **right environment subsection** in the `databases.yml` in my CLI command. And how symfony and / or doctrine handles this by default.

Comment: Maybe the question should be: How to control **from what environment** the connection will be selected using just `Doctrine_Query::create()` from within a symfony CLI task?

Comment: @TommyBravo, Doctrine does not control environment, it is property of Application. I have updated my answer below how to set environment for cli tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cause of my actual problem

After some deep debugging using a cleanly created task I finally found my culprit. Symfony 1.4 seems to run the **`configure`** method of each task in the tasks directory before actually running the intended task.

Unfortunately some uninformed prankster (ex colleague<sup>*</sup>) included some hard coded context initialization into one of these methods like this:

```
// inside a task
protected function configure() {
    // context was initialized
    $configuration    = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('app_name', 'prod', true);
    $context          = sfContext::createInstance($configuration);

    // so the following was available in the configure method
    $save_path = sfConfig::get('sf_app_config_dir');

    // rest of configure method implementation 
    // ...
}
```

This screwed up the database settings for all cronjobs on all other environments except for the production environment (luckily).

I managed to work around it by doing something like this:

```
protected function configure() {
    $configuration    = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('app_name', 'prod', true);
    // removed the context creation

    $configuration->activate(); // this makes the sfConfig::get() work
    $save_path = sfConfig::get('sf_app_config_dir');

    // rest of configure method implementation 
    // ...
}
```

### Answer to my question

Also I found that when it comes to controlling which database connection is used by `Doctrine_Query::create()` you could have some control by using something like this on a higher level function:

```
// for making sure the 'auth' database settings are used as a default
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setCurrentConnection('auth');
```

However, this doesn't have any power over what 'environment section' is used to select the right configuration/dsn for the database. This is done by doing something like this:

```
// somewhere in the execute method
$env              = 'dev'; // the environment section name; 
$configuration    = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('app_name', $env, true);
$context          = sfContext::createInstance($configuration);
```

As also correctly hinted in the answers of [Alex Blex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33605867/839332) and [Marek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33669282/839332). Using a task 'option' for it to make it support multiple environments as they suggest makes sense.

<sub>*:  My ex colleague which I can hardly be mad at because of the unlikeliness and counter intuitive nature of this problem ;)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create($doctrineManager->getConnection('doctrine'))
    ->select('*')
    ->from('Products p')
    ->where('p.id = ?', $productID)
    ->limit(1);
```

should work. Depending on where you select your `Product` from, the parameter  may be 'doctrine', 'log', or 'auth'.

Could you elaborate why you are "not able to set the connection" this way?

**EDIT:**

So if I get it right, you like to specify environment in cli command, to use `dsn` connection string from the right section in `database.yml`. You can use `env` option for your cli commands to do so. You may need to add something like

```
$this->addOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_OPTIONAL, 'Specify environment', 'prod');
```

to the task configuration.

Comment: I have lots of code deeper in the software where `Doctrine_Query::create()` is used (without the connection argument). It seems to select the right environment and connection through web requests. But I can't figure out how it does this, so I can make my **CLI commands** work the same way (they don't select the right connection and environment at the moment). That's why I need to know how to control which connection is 'automaticly' used (selected by default).

Comment: afaik, the last connection in the list become the default one, but since you have connection specified in schema, it doesn't matter. I have updated the answer, but it would be much simpler to answer if you explain in which way you are "not able to set the connection". E.g. copy and paste any errors you see.

Answer (score 2):

By default, task is generated with this code:

```
$databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
$connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();
```

This initializes just the one connection, and does not initialize context. Instead, replace it with this:

```
sfContext::createInstance(new frontendConfiguration($options['env'], true));
```

This will create context, using `application` option of the task. You likely want to set default for it, change the task's `configure()` method to have:

```
    $this->addOptions(array(
        new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name', 'frontend'),
        // ...
    ));
```

Notice I added `frontend` to initialize frontend app. You can also adjust the default for env option.

Comment: I guess I was looking for something like this: I'm giving it a go right now. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: It turns out I was already doing something like this in my code (which didn't seem to work). I'm gonna make a clean test case now to see if this has any effect on the default selected connection config that is used.